# Mysql parent record have multiple records in child table show in one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table

1. user (user_name,user_id)
2. servies (service_id, service_name, user_id)

One each user have manay servics e.g 
user "`john`" have many record in `servies` as `PHP`, `HTML`, `SEO`

I want to show each user services as follow

```
user_name ---------------servies  
john --------------------PHP, HTML,SEO  
Miky --------------------Java, C# , Objective C
```

I want select query of this results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT user_name,GROUP_CONCAT(service_name) FROM user 
JOIN servies
ON user.user_id=servies.user_id
GROUP BY user_name
```

Comment: I suppose you need to add a `, ` as delimiter in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` statement to archieve the expected result.

Comment: The default delimiter is comma,it would be superfluous.

Comment: if user don't have any services then he is skipped in the results
how show that user in this query with empty services column?

Comment: @Shahabi Use LEFT JOIN so it will take all users_id